# Xcode: Is it possible to 'Open Quickly' the right pane of the Assistant Editor?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to 'Open Quickly' in the right pane of the Assistant Editor? This would increase productivity by like 20x

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but depending on your Xcode version you may need to adjust the default behavior in Xcode's preferences.

Use <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the "Open Quicky" input box, and then:

- Use <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the file in the right editor.
- Use <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select where you want to open the file using the arrow keys.

On **Xcode 12**, the default action of <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is to open the file in a new "Tab" (which are new in this release, and different from a "Window Tab"). This is still configurable in the preferences.

On **Xcode 11**, you can split the editor as much as you want. This means <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> by default will open the file in the editor next to where your cursor currently is.

---

This behavior is configurable in Xcode's Preferences, under Navigation:

[image: Xcode Navigation Preferences]

To have <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> open the selected file in the editor on the right of the Xcode window, select "Optional Navigation: Uses Second Editor".

Comment: Just an addition to this answer, when the "Open Quickly" input box is showing, you can also press `alt + shift + enter` to open the small GUI menu (called the "Move Focus To Editor...") from which you can choose to open the new file in a new tab or replace any other open tab.

Comment: @danielhadar just tested myself, it still works in Xcode 11 as expected.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis it opens the file in the window that the cursor isn't in.

Answer (score 62):

Make sure that `Uses Focused Editor` is selected in `Preferences` > `Navigation`:

[image: screenshot]

This way, you can open it by focusing the `Assistant Editor`, pressing <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the `Open Quicky` input box, and just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the selected file, instead of <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

An even easier way is to hold down the Option key and then click on the file.  That will bring open the chosen file in the Assistant Editor.  This works great when you TDD your Swift :)  You can have your tests on the left and option click on the implementation to open on the right.

Answer (score 12):

### Cool thing!

Just to extend the answer you can switch between more then two Tabs or open it new editor tab **cool isn't it?**

• Open multiple assistant editor .

• <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

• Hold <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the selected item.(Used to open any file in Assistant Editor)

• You can also use <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle more and
open new tab if you're not on stacked editor.

• The multiple selection window will appear

[image]

> Note: Make sure you have all editor stacked selected

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Guillaume's answer, be mindful that the editor is not in the single editor mode (I don't know what it should be called officially though) that you can disable by selecting this button, otherwise all navigations become "Uses Focused Editor":

[image: "Unfocus this editor" button]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: misread your question above answer is good, just make sure you click into that pane before trying those commands

Sounds like your looking for some hotkeys, check here for a full list

1. http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/23/xcode-keyboard-shortcuts/
2. http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/9/15/14-xcode-time-saving-shortcuts-memorize-and-improve-your-productivity
3. http://nshipster.com/xcode-key-bindings-and-gestures/

but to open assistant editor use `⌘ command + ⌥ option + ↵ return`